# Different way to put into oracleDB - batchupdate

Tags: java

How can I write this with using no BatchUpdate and batchPreparedStatementSetter? 
Just with queryObject or something like it?

```
@Override
public void batchUpt2(User_FK users) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();


    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO INS_RAZNO.BULK_TEST VALUES (?, ?, ?)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {

            ps.setInt(1, i + 1);
            ps.setLong(2, users.getUser().get(i));
            ps.setInt(3, users.getSys());

        }
        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return users.getUser().size();
        }
    });
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("-------------"+duration+"-----------------");

}
```

Comment: batching is probably the most efficient way to insert a list of rows to the database. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: For loop and PreparedStatementSetter

Comment: I have a task from someone to do it other way. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, if someone wants to see...

```
@Override
public void batchUpt2(User_FK users) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO INS_RAZNO.BULK_TEST VALUES (?, ?, ?)", new PreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            int x;
            for(x = 0; x < users.getUser().size(); ++x) {

            ps.setInt(1, x);
            ps.setLong(2, users.getUser().get(x));
            ps.setInt(3, users.getSys());

        }
        }

    });
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;

    System.out.println("-------------"+duration+"-----------------forEach");

}
```